# Calculating text width

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to calculate text width using jQuery. I'm not sure what, but I am definitely doing something wrong.

So, here is the code:

```
var c = $('.calltoaction');

var cTxt = c.text();

var cWidth =  cTxt.outerWidth();

c.css('width' , cWidth);
```

Comment: So, in what way is that code not working? What does it need to do differently?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

This worked better for me:

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
  var html_org = $(this).html();
  var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
  $(this).html(html_calc);
  var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
  $(this).html(html_org);
  return width;
};
```

Comment: +1 - this truly measures the text, not just the containing block element like brainreavis' solution.

Comment: Slick. +1. It looks like you are missing a semi colon on the third line after `'</span>'`, though it doesn't seem to make a difference (worked with or without it on FF9).

Comment: Be careful with this though... this method will unbind any events on child elements.

Comment: I have tried to use this function in a number of ways, but it keeps returning null. Could someone please post the syntax for how this function is actually used? Do I run the .textWidth() function on a jQuery object? Do I pass text to this function? Do I run the function as a jQuery function (ie $.textWidth(jqObject)? Because none of those options seems to work. Thanks...

Comment: @moosefetcher you would do $(selector).textWidth(); Look here https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#basic-plugin-authoring

Comment: I would add white-space: nowrap to the span element, otherwise if the text is wrapped because the container is too small you'll have a wrong result

Comment: What if there is a css rule that causes the nested span to have a very different font size? But I think this should work well if you know how it works. Btw, I would rather clone it or create a new temp element rather than modifying the original one.

Comment: This didn't work for text that's larger than the container. I came up with a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width/53291346#53291346

Answer (score 90):

Here's a function that's better than others posted because

1. it's shorter
2. it works when passing an `<input>`, `<span>`, or `"string"`.
3. it's faster for frequent uses because it reuses an existing DOM element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/philfreo/MqM76/

```
// Calculate width of text from DOM element or string. By Phil Freo <http://philfreo.com>
$.fn.textWidth = function(text, font) {
    if (!$.fn.textWidth.fakeEl) $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl = $('<span>').hide().appendTo(document.body);
    $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.text(text || this.val() || this.text()).css('font', font || this.css('font'));
    return $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.width();
};
```

Comment: Wow! Pure awesomeness!

Comment: Fantastico! Simple and clean.

Comment: Whilst good, this doesn't handle spaces. See @edsioufi's answer for an enhancement to this solution.

Comment: If there's hidden text inside the element, then it will skew your width. To account for this, be sure to do remove the hidden nodes before calculating the text width. To safely remove the hidden nodes, you should probably make a clone first and do the removal there.

Comment: Magic! handles different font size elegantly. thanks.

Comment: Great solution!  I modified it a little bit.  I just use the element from which the function is called and get that font to pass on to the span.  This saves having to pass in the font itself.

$.fn.widthOfTextInElement = function () {
    if (!$.fn.widthOfTextInElement.fakeEl) $.fn.widthOfTextInElement.fakeEl = $('<span>').hide().appendTo(document.body);
    $.fn.widthOfTextInElement.fakeEl.text($(this).text() || $(this).val())
        .css('font', $(this).css("font"));
    return $.fn.widthOfTextInElement.fakeEl.width();
}

Comment: Nice solution, but it will take time to append and all

Comment: Warning! This thrashes the body-layout! It cost me a day to find it :(

Answer (score 36):

**[My solution](http://jsfiddle.net/bevacqua/h22tj/)**

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
    var self = $(this),
        children = self.children(),
        calculator = $('<span style="display: inline-block;" />'),
        width;

    children.wrap(calculator);
    width = children.parent().width(); // parent = the calculator wrapper
    children.unwrap();
    return width;
};
```

Basically an improvement over Rune's, that doesn't use `.html` so lightly

Comment: **By [Ajarn Gerhard](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1996729/ajarn-gerhard) who posted this as an answer:** This not working in IE8 because you're missing a `/` before the closing bracket of the `<span>` tag: `calculator = $('<span style="display: inline-block;" />'),`

Comment: This seems to return null if there is child element below the element you are measuring. Can it be made to work without the child element? See http://jsfiddle.net/h22tj/41/

Comment: +1 - I never knew there was an unwrap(), that has caused me endless grief.

Comment: It always returns null on Chrome.

Answer (score 12):

The `textWidth` functions provided in the answers and that accept a `string` as an argument will not account for leading and trailing white spaces (those are not rendered in the dummy container). Also, they will not work if the text contains any html markup (a sub-string `<br>` won't produce any output and `&nbsp;` will return the length of one space).

This is only a problem for the `textWidth` functions which accept a `string`, because if a DOM element is given, and `.html()` is called upon the element, then there is probably no need to fix this for such use case.

But if, for example, you are calculating the width of the text to dynamically modify the width of an text `input` element as the user types (my current use case), you'll probably want to replace leading and trailing spaces with `&nbsp;` and encode the string to html.

I used philfreo's solution so here is a version of it that fixes this (with comments on additions):

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(text, font) {
    if (!$.fn.textWidth.fakeEl) $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl = $('<span>').appendTo(document.body);
    var htmlText = text || this.val() || this.text();
    htmlText = $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.text(htmlText).html(); //encode to Html
    htmlText = htmlText.replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp;"); //replace trailing and leading spaces
    $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.html(htmlText).css('font', font || this.css('font'));
    return $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.width();
};
```

Comment: Oddly, when I tried this one, it did not correctly copy the `font-size`. I had to add `css('font-size'), this.css('font-size'))` for it to work. Any ideas why `font` alone does not copy that value?

Comment: @GoneCoding Where did you add those extras?

Comment: @webmagnets: Same place as the existing `.css` method, but I see my brackets are wrong. Should be `css('font-size', this.css('font-size'))`.

Answer (score 11):

jQuery's width functions can be a bit shady when trying to determine the text width due to inconsistent box models. The sure way would be to inject div inside your element to determine the actual text width:

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
  var sensor = $('<div />').css({margin: 0, padding: 0});
  $(this).append(sensor);
  var width = sensor.width();
  sensor.remove();
  return width;
};
```

To use this mini plugin, simply:

```
$('.calltoaction').textWidth();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this give you the block width rather than the text?

Comment: -1 This does indeed seem to measure the width of the box rather than the text width.

Comment: Wouldn't simply using a span instead of a div fix the width problem? If so, then this function is a bit better than the accepted answer.

Comment: @Josh: If you replace it with a `span` you just get zero. Tried this solution on an `H2`, where parent elements have overflow hidden, and I only get the truncated length of the text. Perhaps an explanation of how this is *supposed to work* would help make it work better?

Answer (score 8):

I found this solution works well and it inherits the origin font before sizing:

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(text){
  var org = $(this)
  var html = $('<span style="postion:absolute;width:auto;left:-9999px">' + (text || org.html()) + '</span>');
  if (!text) {
    html.css("font-family", org.css("font-family"));
    html.css("font-size", org.css("font-size"));
  }
  $('body').append(html);
  var width = html.width();
  html.remove();
  return width;
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this, but added `org.css("font-weight")`. Also, I would say that the `if(!text)` part is unintuitive. If I use e.g. `jQuery("#someContainer").textWidth("Lorem ipsum")` I would want to know the text width of "Lorem ipsum" when applied in that particular container.

Answer (score 8):

Neither Rune's nor Brain's was working for me in case when the element that was holding the text had fixed width. I did something similar to Okamera. It uses less selectors.

EDIT:
It won't probably work for elements that uses relative `font-size`, as following code inserts `htmlCalc` element into `body` thus looses the information about parents relation.

```
$.fn.textWidth = function() {
    var htmlCalc = $('<span>' + this.html() + '</span>');
    htmlCalc.css('font-size', this.css('font-size'))
            .hide()
            .prependTo('body');
    var width = htmlCalc.width();
    htmlCalc.remove();
    return width;
};
```

Comment: This was the best solution for me with IE8 support and won't break any binds to the element in the process! Thx.

Comment: note: In a jQuery extension method, `this` is already a jQuery object so `$(this)` is redundant.

Comment: This worked wrongly for me, in that the width calculated is too small. The accepted answer worked correctly

Answer (score 5):

If your trying to do this with text in a select box or if those two arent working try this one instead:

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
 var calc = '<span style="display:none">' + $(this).text() + '</span>';
 $('body').append(calc);
 var width = $('body').find('span:last').width();
 $('body').find('span:last').remove();
 return width;
};
```

or

```
function textWidth(text){
 var calc = '<span style="display:none">' + text + '</span>';
 $('body').append(calc);
 var width = $('body').find('span:last').width();
 $('body').find('span:last').remove();
 return width;
};
```

if you want to grab the text first

Answer (score 4):

the thing, you are doing wrong, that you are calling a method on cTxt, which is a simple string and not a jQuery object. cTxt is really the contained text.

Answer (score 2):

Slight change to Nico's, since .children() will return an empty set if we're referencing a text element like an **h1** or **p**. So we'll use .contents() instead, and use **this** instead of $(this) since we're creating a method on a jQuery object.

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
    var contents = this.contents(),
        wrapper  = '<span style="display: inline-block;" />',
        width    = '';

    contents.wrapAll(wrapper);
    width = contents.parent().width(); // parent is now the wrapper
    contents.unwrap();
    return width;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

after chasing a ghost for two days, trying to figure out why the width of a text was incorrect, i realized it was because of white spaces in the text string that would stop the width calculation.

so, another tip is to check if the whitespaces are causing problems. use

```
&nbsp;
```

non-breaking space and see if that fixes it up.

the other functions people suggested work well too, but it was the whitespaces causing trouble.

Comment: Just temporarily add `white-space: nowrap` to the inline CSS to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to determine the width of a mix of text nodes and elements inside a given element, you need to wrap all the contents with [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/), calculate the width, and then unwrap the contents.

*Note: You will also need to extend jQuery to add an unwrapInner() function since it is not provided by default.

```
$.fn.extend({
  unwrapInner: function(selector) {
      return this.each(function() {
          var t = this,
              c = $(t).children(selector);
          if (c.length === 1) {
              c.contents().appendTo(t);
              c.remove();
          }
      });
  },
  textWidth: function() {
    var self = $(this);
    $(this).wrapInner('<span id="text-width-calc"></span>');
    var width = $(this).find('#text-width-calc').width();
    $(this).unwrapInner();
    return width;
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 for .wrapInner.  As you probably know, dealing with pure text elements in jQuery is hell.  If there are any other jQuery methods that are applicable, please let me know.  I have had to resort to .get(0).children and it's not pretty.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @philfreo's answer:

I've added the ability to check for `text-transform`, as things like `text-transform: uppercase` usually tend to make the text wider.

```
$.fn.textWidth = function (text, font, transform) {
    if (!$.fn.textWidth.fakeEl) $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl = $('<span>').hide().appendTo(document.body);
    $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.text(text || this.val() || this.text())
        .css('font', font || this.css('font'))
        .css('text-transform', transform || this.css('text-transform'));
    return $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.width();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var calc = '<span style="display:none; margin:0 0 0 -999px">' + $('.move').text() + '</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Call getColumnWidth() to get the with of the text. This works perfectly fine.

```
someFile.css
.columnClass { 
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
}


function getColumnWidth(columnClass,text) { 
    tempSpan = $('<span id="tempColumnWidth" class="'+columnClass+'" style="display:none">' + text + '</span>')
          .appendTo($('body'));
    columnWidth = tempSpan.width();
    tempSpan.remove();
return columnWidth;
}
```

Note:- If you want inline .css pass the font-details in  style only.

Answer (score 0):

I modified Nico's code to work for my needs.

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
    var self = $(this),
        children = self.contents(),
        calculator = $('<span style="white-space:nowrap;" />'),
        width;

    children.wrap(calculator);
    width = children.parent().width(); // parent = the calculator wrapper
    children.unwrap();
    return width;
};
```

I'm using [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) as .children() does not return text nodes which I needed. I also found that the returned width was impacted by the viewport width which was causing wrapping so I'm using white-space:nowrap; to get the correct width regardless of viewport width.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
        var w = $('body').append($('<span stlye="display:none;" id="textWidth"/>')).find('#textWidth').html($(this).html()[0]).width();
        $('#textWidth').remove();
        console.log(w);
        return w;
    };
```

almost a one liner.
Gives you the with of the first character

Answer (score 0):

I could not get any of the solutions listed to work 100%, so came up with this *hybrid*, based on ideas from @chmurson (which was in turn based on @Okamera) and also from @philfreo:

```
(function ($)
{
    var calc;
    $.fn.textWidth = function ()
    {
        // Only create the dummy element once
        calc = calc || $('<span>').css('font', this.css('font')).css({'font-size': this.css('font-size'), display: 'none', 'white-space': 'nowrap' }).appendTo('body');
        var width = calc.html(this.html()).width();
        // Empty out the content until next time - not needed, but cleaner
        calc.empty();
        return width;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

### Notes:

- `this` inside a jQuery extension method is already a jQuery object, so no need for all the extra `$(this)` that many examples have.
- It only adds the dummy element to the body once, and reuses it.
- You should also specify `white-space: nowrap`, just to ensure that it measures it *as a single line* (and not line wrap based on other page styling).
- I could not get this to work using `font` alone and had to explicitly copy `font-size` as well. Not sure why yet (still investigating).
- This *does not* support input fields that way `@philfreo` does.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you also need to measure additionally **height** and not only *text*, but also **HTML width**. I took @philfreo answer and made it more flexbile and useful:

```
function htmlDimensions(html, font) {
  if (!htmlDimensions.dummyEl) {
    htmlDimensions.dummyEl = $('<div>').hide().appendTo(document.body);
  }
  htmlDimensions.dummyEl.html(html).css('font', font);
  return {
    height: htmlDimensions.dummyEl.height(),
    width: htmlDimensions.dummyEl.width()
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

text width can be different for different parents, for example if u add a text into h1 tag it will be wider than div or label, so my solution like this:

```
<h1 id="header1">

</h1>

alert(calcTextWidth("bir iki", $("#header1")));

function calcTextWidth(text, parentElem){
    var Elem = $("<label></label>").css("display", "none").text(text);
    parentElem.append(Elem);
  var width = Elem.width();
  Elem.remove();
    return width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with solutions like @rune-kaagaard's for large amounts of text. I discovered this:

```js
$.fn.textWidth = function() {
 var width = 0;
 var calc = '<span style="display: block; width: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; white-space: nowrap;" class="textwidth"><span>' + $(this).html() + '</span></span>';
 $('body').append(calc);
 var last = $('body').find('span.textwidth:last');
 if (last) {
   var lastcontent = last.find('span');
   width = lastcontent.width();
   last.remove();
 }
 return width;
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peeto/9L0tjgdv/104/)
[GitHub](https://github.com/peeto/jqmarquee)

Answer (score 0):

If the field is a fixed-width input or contenteditable div, you can get the horizontal scroll width as scrollWidth

```
      $("input").on("input", function() {
        var width = el[0].scrollWidth;
        
        console.log(width);
      });
```