# jQuery: shorten string length to fit a set width

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a table, and in each cell I want to place strings, but they are much wider than the cell width. To prevent line break, I would like to shorten the strings to fit the cell, and append '...' at end to indicate that the string is much longer.

The table has about 40 rows and has to be done to each cell, so its important that its a quick. Should I use JS/jQuery for this?

How would I do it?

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards,
Marius

Comment: If it were me, I'd much prefer to do this on the server, unless the data is being fetched from a JSON API or something. (Even then it might be nice for the server to do it; depends on the semantics I guess.)

Comment: Here is a good SO post on getting text width. Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery

Comment: I thought about this, however; I wouldnt know the width of the text in px, and would have to leave a room for variable fonts etc for each user.

Comment: See if these help you: http://papermashup.com/truncate-text-with-the-jtruncate-jquery-plugin/ http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/1175 http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/4251

Comment: I really like [jQuery.dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/).

Comment: Is it possible to break the text only after a whole word?

Answer (score 8):

You can use CSS  -- text-overflow: ellipsis  --  for this - with some caveats for certain browsers and workarounds listed here:

[http://mattsnider.com/css/css-string-truncation-with-ellipsis/ (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20100214075229/http://mattsnider.com/css/css-string-truncation-with-ellipsis)

Answer (score 6):

this should do the trick where 8 is is the the size of the text you want to keep

```
 $('td').each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0,8)+"...");
 });
```

to answer you comment I think jquery [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) should help get you going but I think your headed up a slippery slop you should consider something different like putting the text in a div or using [flexigrid](http://code.google.com/p/flexigrid/) or [jgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6)

Comment: How do I find calculate how wide each letter is to determine  substring second argument?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Use my jQuery plugin: *jQuery-Shorten*.** It handles all the cases, makes use of text-overflow:ellipsis if available and it's very fast.

Download:
[github.com/MarcDiethelm/jQuery-Shorten](http://github.com/MarcDiethelm/jQuery-Shorten)

Demo & Doc:
http://web5.me/jquery/plugins/shorten/shorten.doc.html

You can configure how the text ends (ellipsis). The default is a three-dot char ("…", &hellip;, Unicode: 2026) but you can use anything you want, including markup.

The text width of the 'selected' element (eg. span or div) is measured using Canvas or by placing it inside a temporary table cell and shortened (initially using an educated guess for efficiency) and measured again until it (and the appended ellipsis or text) fits inside the block. A tooltip on the 'selected' element displays the full original text.

Comment: Nice plugin. I think it is worth mentioning that it carries a GPL 3.0 license, which may not fit with everyone's needs.