# Fit text to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with fixed height and width and inside I have text that is changing. Sometimes it can be a word or two and sometimes it can be a sentence. What I need is to shrink the font size so the text fits to that div.

Comment: Do you have a monospace font within the div?

Comment: you should check my answer for a better performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had an idea and it worked :) here is my code

```
        $('li').each(function () {
            while ($(this).outerHeight() > 25) {
                var currentFontSize = $(this).css("font-size");
                $(this).css("font-size", (parseFloat(currentFontSize) - 1) + "px");
            }

        });
```

Comment: +1
I had problems getting the width of text that was wrapped in a div with an explicit width.  I used this solution -->  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2771544/374866

Comment: I have to say that this function is far too slow. Changing css attributes causes a redraw of the dom. If you need to adjust the size of a lot of elements or on a timer it will hog down your webpage. Check my answer for a more efficient but still simple solution

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, which made me write my own plugin for this. One solution is to use the shrink-to-fit-approach, as described by user54316. 
However if you have to fit multiple items or are concerned with performance, e.g., on window resize, have a look at [jquery-quickfit](https://github.com/chunksnbits/jquery-quickfit).

It meassures and calculates a size invariant meassure for each letter of the text to fit and uses this to calculate the next best font-size which fits the text into the container.

The calculations are cached, which makes it very fast (there is virtually no performance hit from the 2nd resize on forward) when dealing with multiple texts or having to fit a text multiple times, like e.g., on window resize. I think it would work perfect in your case.

You'd just have to call

```
$('#yourid').quickfit()
```

after you changed the text.

[Production example, fitting 14x16x2 texts](http://www.four-downs.com/livedrafts/13533)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the font-size in em:

http://clagnut.com/blog/348/

http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plugin for that: FitText.js

Here the URL: https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/martinschaer/sRvB9/

The function fitText() receives a parameter, with which you need to "play" in order to get the results you want. Also, it resized the text when the window is resized; if you need to have the text resized when (for example) a div is resized, you should add a pair of JS lines for that ;)

Comment: This is for a resize of the window, but it's not allowing longer strings to be reduced in size to fit inside a div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text.css('font-size', "100px");
$text.css('line-height', "100px");
var foo= $div.width()    / $text.width();
var bar= $div.height()   / $text.height();

if(foo < bar) {
    foo=Math.floor(foo*100) +"px";
    $text.css('font-size', foo);
    $text.css('line-height', foo);
} else {
    bar=Math.floor(bar*100) +"px";
    $text.css('font-size', bar);
    $text.css('line-height', bar);
}

//centralizing text, top and left are defined as 50% on the CSS, optional
$text.css('margin-left', -$text.width()  /2 + "px");
$text.css('margin-top',  -$text.height() /2 + "px");
```

One small note is that you need to call this function if the div itself changes size. You can bind this code to the resize eventof the div.

Answer (score -2):

you can do it by defining the font size like......

`.small {font-size: 0.8em}`

you can see effect here  [working demo](http://shapeshed.com/examples/font-size-css/)