# Force an input to display inline with automatic width

Tags: css, html

I have a readonly HTML `<input>` that I'd like to display just like a `<span>`.

However, applying the following CSS causes it to stay as `inline-block` in Chrome v34 on Windows.

```css
input[readonly] {
  background:none; color:inherit; /* normal colors     */
  border:0; margin:0; padding:0;  /* no special sizing */
  width:auto; display:inline;     /* try to make it inline and auto-size */
}
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/52vL3/

How can I make the input stop requiring an explicit size, using CSS?

Comment: I'm using an `<input>` here instead of a `<span>` or `<output>` because the element can toggle between being editable by the user or not, and I'd prefer not to have to swap elements in and out.

Comment: good question... Even with it being inline, there is a space like a padding on the right side when you reduce the width down

Comment: example : set the width to 25px and leave everything else the same

Comment: `contenteditable` span instead of an input an option?

Comment: @BrettWeber Thank you, but the size of the content can vary.

Comment: Maybe a better solution is to replace control on the fly? Using span for read-only; using input - well for input. Otherwise you can try to simulate it: http://jsfiddle.net/52vL3/2/ but I am afraid this is not a universal solution and will require many tweaks

Comment: pretty hacky and not a solution but I did this : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/52vL3/3/

Comment: I wasn't intending that as a solution, but an example of why this idea may be highly flawed. The alternative is less hacky

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of things happening here, but inline-block is not your problem. This can be shown by adding

```
-webkit-appearance: none
```

You'll now have an inline input that's still not resizing itself. The problem is that inputs don't automatically size themselves to their value, even when inline.

If it were a `type="text"` input, you could set `size="2"` (default is 20) on the input and it would resize it accordingly (albeit with a bit of extra space).

Unfortunately, `type="number"` ignores the size attribute.

So, you could try using a pattern instead of `type="number"`

```
<input value="64" type="text" pattern="\d*" size="2" readonly>
```

You may want to increase the size when you make it editable though, because the input won't automatically expand to fit wider values.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100770/auto-scaling-inputtype-text-to-width-of-value) for an approach to auto-sizing an input as you type.

Or, depending on how you're using it, you might like to consider `<span contenteditable="true">`