# Make an input adapt to its text

Tags: jquery, html, html-input

I have tried different ways to make an input adapt to is text. The closer I get with jQuery is:  `$("div").attr("size", $("div").val().length );`

I think this works with the attribute size, but this does not seem to measure very well the text. It seems that size works well to measure numbers but not text:

```
<input type="text" id="first" name="first" size="11" value="this has 11">
<br>
<input type="text" id="second" name="second" size="11" value="12345678901">
<br>
<input type="text" id="third" name="third" size="22" value="this has 22 characters">
```

So, when I use size with jQuery:

```
$("#jQ").attr("size", $("#jQ").val().length );
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="jQ" name="jQ" value="text, text, text">
```

Here is the example to play: http://jsfiddle.net/auk7g40m/

Is there a better way to make an input adapt to its text?

Comment: fiddle link is broken.

Comment: The size attribute uses an average character width for the given font size. If you want an exact width, you would need to use a hidden element, updated a the input is typed into and set to the same font properties, and take the width from that.

Comment: So there is no issue? You're just looking for a better alternative. You should post on the code review stack exchange.

Comment: You want the input to change width according to its characters?

Comment: @ramon, I want the input to change according to is characters. I suppose I have the specify in some way the font and size.

Comment: Your question is duplicated

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100770/auto-scaling-inputtype-text-to-width-of-value

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using a monotype font where all the characters have the same width, the easiest way to get the width of a string is to append it to an element, and get the width of the element, like this

```
$("#jQ").css('width', function() {
    var el = $('<span />', {
        text : this.value, 
        css  : {left: -9999, position: 'relative'}
    }).appendTo('body');
    var w = el.css('width');
    el.remove();
    return w;
});
```

Note that setting the height and width of an element doesn't really do anything unless the element has position and is not static.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/auk7g40m/3/)

To make the width follow the keys as they are pressed, you'd just wrap that in an event handler

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/auk7g40m/5/)

Comment: @Nrc - That's where you'll need an event handler, and I added two fiddles in the answer, try the second one.

Comment: I tred the second fiddle with more text

Comment: @Nrc - And you're saying it doesn't work, when you add text to the last input it doesn't increase in size ?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps there is something I do not understand. I tried here: http://jsfiddle.net/auk7g40m/9/

Comment: @Nrc - seems to work just fine for me? What browser are you using ?

Comment: I use Safari, it does not work. Now that you say I tried with Firefox and Chrome and it works better there.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the `input` event that is causing that, but it should work in Safari just fine, so that's strange ?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is set the font of the inputs to a monospace font so that all characters have the same width.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach which might be viable depending on your situation would be to use divs instead of inputs and add the `contenteditable` attribute.

Then add some simple css to create the look of an input element

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/auk7g40m/8/)** (Add some text to the 'inputs' to see them grow)

### CSS

```
div {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0; 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You need onKeyPress function (iv just added the js into the html itself as an example)

```
<input id="first" type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';">
```

Comment: If the user deletes all the characters, it would be a problem with your function.

Comment: not every letter has 8px width. It depends on the font in use