# Auto-scaling issue: it is scaling with character's count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change a `input text` size when I change its value.

I have this javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    function resizeInput() {
        $(this).attr('size', $(this).val().length);
    }

    $('input[type="text"]')
        // event handler
        .keyup(resizeInput)
        // resize on page load
        .each(resizeInput);

    document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function ()
    {
        document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
        $("#uploadFile").attr('size', $("#uploadFile").val().length);
    };
});
```

First, I have test `$('input[type="text"]')` with `resizeInput` function. But it doesn't work.

Next, I have added that function to `document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function ()` but it also doesn't work.

I want to resize input field `uploadFile` when I do this:
`document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;`

How can I auto-scale an input size when I assign it a new string? Now it is autoscaling but it changes input's size with string characters count, and this is not what do I want to do.

I have used this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8100949/68571) as inspiration.

I have added this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VansFannel/mv16t2as/1/) but I'm getting an error.

Comment: insteaf of `$(this).attr('size', $(this).val().length);` try `$(this).css('font-size', $(this).val().length);`

Comment: `$(this).attr('font-size', $(this).val().length);`

Comment: In your resizeInput(), can you console.log($(this)); ? Because I don't think you have the input at hand..

Answer (score 0):

Try this: change `size` value as per length of value entered.

```js
$(function(){
  $("input[type='text']").keyup(function(){
     var value = $(this).val();
     $(this).attr("size",value.length);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Actually your code should work. You have define javascript function inside document.ready, just move it outside or make it jquery function.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $("input[type='text']").keyup(resizeInput);
});
function resizeInput() {
    $(this).attr('size', $(this).val().length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to resize input field `uploadFile` when I do this: `document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;`

Comment: see my updated answer, you have to keep you resizeInput javascript function outside the document.ready. try this.

Comment: And now $(this) will actually be the input =)

Comment: I have added this https://jsfiddle.net/VansFannel/mv16t2as/1/ but it doesn't work. I', getting a POST error.

Comment: You have not added jquery library in jsfiddle. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/mv16t2as/3/), I have added jquery lib in External Resources (on left side menu)