# bootstrap input-group dynamic width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make bootstrap input-group input element width dynamic? I tried setting width: auto; but the input-group still seems to have a set width.

```
<form class="col-sm-12 form-horizontal">
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <ul class="form-group list-inline list-unstyled">
    <li class="" ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div class="input-group list-item">
        <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control" value="{{item}}" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="removeExpedition(item)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</form>
```

and css:

```
.list-item>.input-group-btn {
    width: auto;
}
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2uEsFVa7g84qvJaoWdFM?p=preview%22plunker%22) to demonstrate. See all the whitespace between the input and button. I would like to have the button right next to the input element, with a set padding.

Comment: if I'am right you need the button to take 100% of the width ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.list-inline > li, .input-group {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I tried this with no luck. the input-group goes to 1 per line

Comment: Maybe I still don't understand. Do you want to put all input groups into 1 row?

Comment: not necessarily. Currently each input-group is the same width. I don't want that. I want each input-group to be only as big as needed for the text and "X" button. I need to eliminate the extra whitespace in each input-group between the text and the "X" button. so the input-group. Thus the input group with the text "3" would not be as wide as the input-group with the text "And_one_more"

Answer (score 0):

there is built in class in bootstrap to do this.
just give the button class ( `btn-block` )

Comment: where should I add it? Doesn't seem to work in the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Add to li elements style `display: block` and add to div.input-group class `btn-block` that's all

Comment: this seems to make the input-group fill the entire div

Comment: Oh, now I unserstand what you want to achieve, you can't do this with only CSS or boostrap, all you need is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100770/auto-scaling-inputtype-text-to-width-of-value

Answer (score 0):

okay, so I was able to do this by using a btn-group instead of an input-group. The input was being used only to show a value, so it wasn't necessary. btn-group by default is only a wide as the text it includes.