# Expanding quantity Html Input width based on user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

what would be the best way to auto-expand an input field based on user input?

I have an issue below where if there is more than 2 numbers the quantity input gets cut off, and there can be up to say 7 numbers... so I would like it to auto-expand.

If there's a css only solution that would be fabulous. Otherwise that's ok :-)

See below where the quantity is 166578 it doesn't show the full amount:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Post your code, looks like you're limiting it with something. A `select` box will do that by default. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/OgeJEZ

Comment: You probably need to write some JS, look here for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100770/auto-scaling-inputtype-text-to-width-of-value

Answer (score 0):

I think you could set the [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) attribute to true and set a `min-width` and `max width` in the CSS.