# Setup jQuery UI Spinner to adjust width so text fits in

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, spinner

I am looking at this jQuery UI Spinner example https://jqueryui.com/spinner/ and I notice that its default width of the input area is much bigger than the actual string inside. How to configure the widget so its width gets automatically adjusted and I can see just the text inside the input box, without any whitespaces before it?

Example:

Instead of this:

```
[   10]
```

I want to see just this:

```
[10]
```

But when the text grows further, it should grow to fit it:

```
[100]
```

Note: I am familiar with HTML <input type="text"> size attribute, which lets me specify a hardcoded size (in chars) of the input, but I don't see such a setting here: https://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/ . Is it because the widgets inherit all properties of the input widget transparently or this can be done differently? I am willing to accept this approach as the particular workaround if the goal stated in the question can't be achieved for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100770/auto-scaling-inputtype-text-to-width-of-value). So I mixed it with https://jqueryui.com/spinner/. We can detect the value changing by `_format` event and call the `resizeInput` method inside it:

```
$.widget( "ui.pcntspinner", $.ui.spinner, {
    _format: function( value ) { intputElem.each(resizeInput); return value; },
});
```

And it worked. Try it yourself at [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x72X9/191/).