# break-word to next line td in html table jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with fixed count of `td` and `tr`. Rows and cols have fixed width and height. Every `td` has `input type="text"` inside. How can I move to next `tr` the text, which does not fit in `td` length?

Example table:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table style="width:100px">
      <tr style="height:12px">
        <td style="width=50px"><input type="text" style="width:100%" value="12 34 56 44"></td>
        <td style="width=50px"><input type="text" style="width:100%" value="786 5"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width=50px"><input type="text" style="width:100%" value=""></td>
        <td style="width=50px"><input type="text" style="width:100%" value=""></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

There are values of top-left `input` dont' fit in the length of the top-left `td`.

How can I penetrate values from top-left `input` to the next cell `input` below, which not fit in length of the top-left `td` using jquery ?

Here possible result:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table style="width:100px">
      <tr style="height:12px">
        <td style="width=50px"><input type="text" style="width:100%" value="12 34"></td>
        <td style="width=50px"><input type="text" style="width:100%" value="786 5"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width=50px"><input type="text" style="width:100%" value="56 44"></td>
        <td style="width=50px"><input type="text" style="width:100%" value=""></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: May be helpful:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100770/auto-scaling-inputtype-text-to-width-of-value

Comment: Thanks, but I can't resize the table, tr, td and inputs width/height

Comment: I guess Alive to Die did link that particular post, because it shows you how to get / limit the length of the content of the input element. It is not a direct answer to your question, apply it for your purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `scrollWidth` to check if the text has overflown

here is the code snippet.
just notice that I added two Ids to two inputs just for simplicity, you can remove them and change jquery code easily if you want.

```js
while($('#in')[0].scrollWidth > $('#in').innerWidth()){
  var inputText = $('#in').val();
  var last = inputText.substr(inputText.length - 1);
  $('#in').val(inputText.slice(0,-1));
  $('#out').val($('#out').val() +''+ last);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <table style="width:100px">
      <tr style="height:12px">
        <td style="width=50px"><input type="text" id="in" style="width:100%" value="12 34 56 44"></td>
        <td style="width=50px"><input type="text" style="width:100%" value="786 5"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width=50px"><input type="text" id="out" style="width:100%" value=""></td>
        <td style="width=50px"><input type="text" style="width:100%" value=""></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```