# CSS / HTML Table: How to autogrowth a column width based on the text value of the input element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I have a table on React (Using AntD); but it doesn't matter for the question...

The issue is, that I want that cells of a specific column render text inputs... that this it's fine.

But, if I render only text inside the `td` element, the HTML table auto-width the column based on the longest value in the table... but if I render an `input` the auto-width doesn't work.
I don't want to fix the column width (using px or %); I want the column with the `inputs` auto-growth depending on the longest value in the cells.

Here is the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-browser-v54fh?file=/src/columnsRender.js

This is a screenshot:

[image: Example 1]

This is another example:

[image: Example 2]

In the first example; looks almost good...
In the second; it's so much space in the first column (The second column fits perfectly based on the data or in the header).

So, it's possible that a `td` element understand the width of an `input` element and automatically fixes the width of the column in the table?
Or exists any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking out the possibilities, in a short answer. Just with CSS we cannot achieve something like this scenario.

But, as a workaround that almost works perfectly, I read each change and take the length of the string, and change the style not using `px` or `%`... instead of, I use `ch` to change the `width` of the input.

An additional setting, I put the style in all inputs of the same column with a `min-width` of `100%`.

Here is an example:[image: Example]

The full example you can find it here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-thunder-z9qfb?file=/src/columnsRender.js

Using `react`, I made a custom hook to manipulate some events and keep all centralized.

Answer (score 1):

> *So, it's possible that a td element understand the width of an input element and automatically fixes the width of the column in the table?*

It's actually that the input element doesn't understand the width of its content.
The table doesn't know how wide to be, because the input doesn't know how wide to be. [Check out these answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100770/auto-scaling-inputtype-text-to-width-of-value)

Comment: Seems I need extra logic to evaluate and change the width with code. Thanks for the reference!