# Auto-scaling input to width of value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, resize

I want to have an input whose width adapts to fit its content.

I'm trying to implement [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38867270/5308892), but using React:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default () => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);

  const changeHandler = evt => {
    setContent(evt.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <wrapper>
      <span id="hide">{content}</span>
      <input type="text" autoFocus style={{ width }} onChange={changeHandler} />
    </wrapper>
  );
};
```

The problem is I don't know how to then query the width of the span, in order to then change the width of the input (using `setWidth`).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling around, I found a solution!

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export default () => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const span = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    setWidth(span.current.offsetWidth);
  }, [content]);

  const changeHandler = evt => {
    setContent(evt.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <wrapper>
      <span id="hide" ref={span}>{content}</span>
      <input type="text" style={{ width }} autoFocus onChange={changeHandler} />
    </wrapper>
  );
};
```

To get a reference to the `#hide` span I employ `useRef`. Then, the `width` state variable can be updated via the function defined inside `useEffect`, which gets called everytime `content` changes.

I also had to switch the `display: none` in the css of `#hide` for `position: absolute` and `opacity: 0`, as otherwise `targetRef.current.offsetWidth` would always evaluate to 0.

Here's [a working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cabralpinto/h32wob50/1/).

Comment: works with formik... decent hack...!!

Comment: nice one! working well for me in 2023. don't forget to also set `pointer-events: none;` in `#hide`'s css

Comment: Nice! I found that with `visibility: hidden;` you don't need the opacity and z-index tricks. Unless I'm missing something...

Answer (score 8):

Well, this was interesting enough!
I tried a few different ideas that I had, but none of them worked perfectly - especially not if they were to be written in a somewhat respectable code.

I found this post however and decided to try that out.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43488899/3293843

I am sure there are flaws with it, one for example is that it does act funny unless I use a monospaced font. But maybe there are some css tricks to get around that?

```js
// Normally I'd go for ES6 imports, but to make it run as a StackOverflow snippet I had to do it this way
const { useState, useRef } = React;

const GrowingInput = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  
  const changeHandler = evt => {
    setWidth(evt.target.value.length);
  };
 
  return (
    <input style={{ width: width +'ch'}} type="text" autoFocus onChange={changeHandler} />
  )
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <p>Lorem ipsum {<GrowingInput />} egestas arcu.</p>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
input {
  font-family: Courier;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Have you considered using a `contenteditable` instead?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Comment: Check the solution I just posted (works with proportional fonts!)

Comment: That looks very similar to my first approach. The thing is that the reference was one click away affecting the input in a way that all characters were not 100% visible. 
I also had another test were the input would grow too long. Could you put it in a runable snippet? I was also not fond of positioning the span with absolute (which I also did)... maybe a portal is a better solution instead? But, if it works for you - that is great

Answer (score 2):

Found out a trick using Refs in react.

```
style={{ width: inputRef.current ? inputRef.current.value.length + 'ch' : 'auto' }}
```

And set the `ref={inputRef}` for the  element.
Do remember to set the min-width for the input in your CSS.

Comment: It's not dynamic

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest solution I've found.

You create a function that you'll use on change

```
   const handleChangeAndSize = (ev: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      const target = ev.target;
      target.style.width = '60px';
      target.style.width = `${target.scrollWidth}px`;

      handleChange(ev);
   };
```

Then you use it as a regular function in your component

```
<input type='text' onChange={handleChangeAndSize}/>
```

The style.width = 60px will allow to resize the input when shrinking, and the target.scrollWidth will watch the 'scrollable width' on x axis and set it as width.

Nb: credit to this guy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87wfMZ56egU