# How can I change the text size in a input type text based on the length of the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input type text like:

```
<label class="NoAfter" for="ProjectTitle">
    Project Title: 
    <input id="ProjectTitle" type="text" style="width:250px;" name="ProjectTitle" value="" required>
</label>
```

I would like to adjust the font size as the user types. I can't use a jQuery plug-in so I would like a javascript solution or a jQuery solution without a plug-in.

Comment: Not using a jQuery plugin is an odd requirement. There are lots that do this. If you can't add a plugin to the page, why not find an MIT licensed one and copy the logic from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6114440/4861207), but did change from `keyup` to `keydown`, this way, if you click and hold on a character, it will still resize itself

You need to separate out the font-size declaration and scale it appropriately. Depending on how you're doing things, this might be easiest if you break out the different parts of the font declaration. A resize function might look like this (again, obviously, this is jQuery-dependent):

#### JSFiddle

```js
// txt is the text to measure, font is the full CSS font declaration,
// e.g. "bold 12px Verdana"
function measureText(txt, font) {
  var id = 'text-width-tester',
    $tag = $('#' + id);
  if (!$tag.length) {
    $tag = $('<span id="' + id + '" style="display:none;font:' + font + ';">' + txt + '</span>');
    $('body').append($tag);
  } else {
    $tag.css({
      font: font
    }).html(txt);
  }
  return {
    width: $tag.width(),
    height: $tag.height()
  }
}

function shrinkToFill(input, fontSize, fontWeight, fontFamily) {
  var $input = $(input),
    txt = $input.val(),
    maxWidth = $input.width() + 5, // add some padding
    font = fontWeight + " " + fontSize + "px " + fontFamily;
  // see how big the text is at the default size
  var textWidth = measureText(txt, font).width;
  if (textWidth > maxWidth) {
    // if it's too big, calculate a new font size
    // the extra .9 here makes up for some over-measures
    fontSize = fontSize * maxWidth / textWidth * .9;
    font = fontWeight + " " + fontSize + "px " + fontFamily;
    // and set the style on the input
    $input.css({
      font: font
    });
  } else {
    // in case the font size has been set small and 
    // the text was then deleted
    $input.css({
      font: font
    });
  }
}

$(function() {
  $('#my_input').keydown(function() {
    shrinkToFill(this, 20, "", "Georgia, serif");
  })
});
```

```css
input {
  font: 20px Georgia, serif;
  width: 150px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="my_input">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you don't want to use any jquery plugin then the simplest answer is here :

```html
<label class="NoAfter" for="ProjectTitle">
    Project Title: 
    <input id="ProjectTitle" type="text" style="width:250px;" name="ProjectTitle" value=""  onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';"  required >
</label>
```

Enjoy !!!!!!!!!!!!
Have a good day

Comment: This is changing the size of the input not the size of the text, but I like it! (if that any consolation) Can it be changed to change the font-size?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a key up event for the input and modify fontsize for the input.

```
document.getElementById("ProjectTitle").onkeyup = function() {
    var value = document.getElementById("ProjectTitle").value;
    if(value.length > 2){
       document.getElementById("ProjectTitle").style['font-size'] = "12px";
    }else{
       document.getElementById("ProjectTitle").style['font-size'] = "14px";
    }
}
```