# Font scaling based on width of input

Tags: css, input, responsive-design, font-size

How can I shrink the font size of a text-input, so that it doesn't overflow if the user enters a long text?

**Setting:**

- the text-input is sized by `flex-grow`
- the maximum font-size should be fixed (e.g. 12pt)
- the height of the text-input shouldn't resize, i.e. be fixed for font-size 12pt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shrinking font-size at a user types to fit in an input using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114300/shrinking-font-size-at-a-user-types-to-fit-in-an-input-using-javascript)

Comment: Sounds good. Give me a second to try it

Comment: Right now it doesn't work perfectly. Let me see, if I can fix it myself

Comment: @tmdesigned I could reproduce it in the fiddle, given by the answer. Maybe you know, why it doesn't work properly if you insert i.e. "Maaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" in the text field