# How do I dynamically adjust size to fit text?

Tags: jquery, css, facebox

I am using Rails3 + jQuery to build an app using Facebox.

In the facebox, the title text is too big to fit in a single line, so it is being spread into two lines. It looks ugly, so I was wondering whether there was a way to either:

1. Adjust the size of the title dynamically to fit the facebox width.
2. Dynamically adjust the facebox width to fit the title text on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer fits your needs: [Calculating text width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery/1582678#1582678)