# Finding text width in jquery

Tags: jquery, text, width

I am trying to to calculate text width in px.

I will take a string from html, this string may contain some special characters as well (in this example just a hyphen), and make this string an html content of a div, and calculate string width.

But I am getting strange results.

If there is an better way to get text width, cross-browser!, please let me know.

I have made a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/YaPcP/39/

Thank you!

Comment: You are calculating the width of the div. And as you didn't give him any width in the css, it takes all the window width.

Comment: Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript

Comment: Duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery

Comment: I found this, maybe it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float: left;` to `#holder`

`#holder` which is the test container for width, is defaulting to `width: auto;`. In other words, it is spanning 100% of the browser window and giving you the mixed results.

You might consider adding `white-space: nowrap;` as well to `#holder` should it ever exceed the width of it's container.

Updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/YaPcP/44/)

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` elements are set to span the width of their parent element, so changing the font size will have no effect on its actual width.  Changing your `<div>` to a `<span>` should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: I edited original a little bit: http://jsfiddle.net/YaPcP/50/. The only problem is it doesnt give the same results in every browser. In IE9 it almost 10px off and in Opera like 30px off.

Answer (score 0):

It may look nasty but gives you the width:

http://jsfiddle.net/adaz/YaPcP/43/