# How do I get text width in pixels, using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get textarea text width. How do I get text width in pixels?

I do not want the text length.

Comment: You mean the width of your textarea?

Comment: how about checking this first..?::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply wrap the text in a (invisible) `span` and use [jQuerys .width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) to get the width.

Note that you should *not*, like others said, use a `div` as it's a block-element - and depending on where/how you insert that, a block-element may auto-expand to the full available width and give bad results.