# How to calculate width of an line of text in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to calculate just the width of one line of text with jquery.

I have the following text in an string

> "Line 1
>
> Line 2
>
> Line 3
>
> Line 4 Blah
>
> Line 5"

When testing to find the width of the text which is shown on the page it always shows 77 px from where line 4 is the longest.

The text is put in using Jquery command .append() on the element id #text

the code used for the element is

```
<div id = 'terminal'><pre><span id = 'text'></span></pre>
```

How would I calculate just the width of Line 5?

Thanks - Ryan

Comment: perhaps this could help you as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057682/determine-pixel-length-of-string-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get text width in pixel javascript or jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782687/how-to-get-text-width-in-pixel-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: I'm already wrapping an selection of text in an span element to do it but I don't think how i'm trying to do the text will work with multiple spans.

Comment: `span`s are inline elements, then don't influence the text flow. If you do it correctly, it will work. Since you are not showing how you are doing it, we cannot help you with that.

Comment: I added in a little bit of text @FelixKling

Comment: You have to put every line in a `span` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - **demo:** http://jsbin.com/otaquf/5

```
$(function(){
  var text =  $.trim($('#demo').text());
  // this may vary browser to browser...
  var text_w_no_empty_lines = text.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '\n');
  var lines = text_w_no_empty_lines.split('\n');
  // line number you want  total - 1
  var line_5 = lines[4];
  // .tick { white-space:nowrap;display:inline-block;display:none }
  alert( $('<p class="tick">').html(line_5).appendTo('body').width() )
});
```

---

```
        <p id="demo" style="white-space:pre">
        Line 1

        Line 2

        Line 3

        Line 4 Blah

        Line 5
        </p>
```

> - **NOTE:** the trick here is to use css `white-space:pre` to mantain the real height and pre style

Comment: And the height gives the width of the last line?

Comment: OP wants to measure each line, not the entire element.

Answer (score 0):

Put the strings in multiple div elements and use .width() on the 5th.

Answer (score 0):

You can append your text to a div with width:auto, and take that div's width.

something like this:

```
var auxDiv = $("<div>").css({width : "auto"}).appendTo($("body")).html("<div id = 'terminal'><pre><span id = 'text'></span></pre>");

var widthOfText = auxDiv.width();
auxDiv.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<style>.temp{display:none}</style>
​<pre class="preview"></pre>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
​<span class="temp"></span>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var string = 'line 1\nline 2 ... \nline 3..',
        lines = string.split('\n'),
        $temp = $('.temp').show();

    $('.preview').html(string);

    $.each(lines, function(key, str) {
        console.log(key + ': ' + $temp.html(str).width())
    })
    $temp.hide();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

no need of jquery... tou can just use the `offsetWidth` property of the element in the DOM