# dynamically add marquee content using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to add the contents like  in marquee using jquery? Basically, I want to add the different latest images for my website.

Thanks.

Comment: don't use marquee. it's *highly* annoying.

Comment: Follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593568/dynamic-content-for-jquery-marquee-dynamic-width-also

Comment: @anishsane then what I should use? I want to show the latest updates moving upword.

Comment: I meant, as a good practise, avoid marquee & blink as much as possible. Maybe, it's a **requirement** in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if there's an agreed definition of marquee. In the context of HTML I always thought it means a text scrolling from **right to left** (or LTR).

I see in the comments you want items moving **upward**. There're surely some JQuery plugins to do it, but you can easily do it yourself. HTML:

```
<ul id="panel_news">
    <li>BigEvent 2012 @ Berlin, 29 Nov - 1 Dec</li>
    <li>User Group meeting hosted by ConnectUs</li>
    <li>Joan announces PXLS</li>
    <li>OpenVMS Boot Camp</li>
</ul>
<ul id="panel_news_bank" style="display: none;">
    <li>IT annual conference in Melbourne</li>
    <li>Benchmark presenation</li>
</ul>
```

​
and JavaScript/JQuery code:

```
var tickerTimer = self.setInterval("ticker()", 2500);
function ticker() {
    $("#panel_news > li").first().hide(500, function() {
        var ticker_item;
        $("#panel_news > li").first().detach().appendTo("#panel_news_bank");
        ticker_item = $("#panel_news_bank > li").first().detach();
        ticker_item.appendTo("#panel_news");
        ticker_item.fadeIn(1000);
        ticker_item = null;
    });
}
```

see it in action @ [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/targumon/Xs4nC/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this JQuery plugin for marquee:

http://www.givainc.com/labs/marquee_jquery_plugin.htm