# How to get the width of whitespace?

Tags: html, css

I have a function to cut string to a exactly width , we called this `cut()`

`cut('abcd',3) = 'abc'`

the font-family I use is `Arial`

but when I calculate each charater's width , I found `whitespace` is strange.

```
<span id='x'> </span>
```

when I use `$("#x").width()` I got 0.0

Note that `whitespace` is not `&nbsp`

Why `' ' = 0.0` but in `'a b' that ' ' != 0.0`

What's the rule of `whitespace` in `HTML` ?

Comment: Your title does not match your question... "width of whitespace" feels like width of rendered character in a string, but your question in the post seem to be "how elements with no/whitespace only content are rendered".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `white-space: pre;` to force spaces to render as they're written:

```
#x {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

I get a width of `4px`: http://jsfiddle.net/qgeUZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this, as featured here : [Calculating text width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery)

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
      var html_org = $(this).html();
      var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
      $(this).html(html_calc);
      var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
      $(this).html(html_org);
      return width;
    };
```

//cut function