# Determine if expanded text will exceed max-width/cause ellipsis to show?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to determine if a block of text is cut-off/showing an ellipsis so that I can conditionally add a `[more]` link after it.

Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
.more-text-collapse {
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:400px;
    height:1.2em;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Which I apply to a `<div>`. When the text inside exceeds 400px it displays an ellipsis at the end. In that scenario I want to add a `[more]` link to expand the text.

How can I determine if I need to display the link?

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/wxvRf/)

Comment: Don't use the CSS ellipsis. You can't archive what you are trying to do using that. Its also not supported were openly.

Comment: @Shawn31313: Why can't I achieve what I'm trying to do with that? And even if the ellipsis doesn't show, it will still be cut-off. `overflow:hidden` is pretty well supported, no?

Comment: It is. No need to get all defensive. But here is just a little example of how I would do it: http://jsfiddle.net/SRvuQ/1 ....the code isn't very pretty but that was because I was just quickly writing that. This might also not be the best way though. Because javascript has to hide the text.

Comment: @Shawn31313: You're basing that on number of characters, which is sub-optimal. Some messages might contain really skinny characters, whereas others might contain wide characters. You'd have quite the variance in overall width. Plus, this solution won't support basic text formatting such as bolding and italics.

Comment: Yeah. I know i'm basing it of characters.

Answer (score 2):

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery), here you go with the code:

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
  var html_org = $(this).html();
  var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
  $(this).html(html_calc);
  var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
  $(this).html(html_org);
  return width;
};

var elmW = $('.more-text').width(),
    txtW = $('.more-text').textWidth();
if(elmW < txtW) $('.more-text').after('[more]');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sergiu/EvD3J/1/

Comment: There's a few things I don't like about this. You're replacing the element's contents and then quickly swapping it back. First, in theory, this could cause some flicker, secondly, it will de-bind any event handlers to the contents (it's destructive), third, the `span:first` selector is more complicated than it needs to be considering there are no other children...it should also be noted that this won't work without `white-space:nowrap`.

Comment: I just made use of that function w/o making any change. If you know another way to calculate the text width, you are welcome to use it ;)

Comment: The idea is OK, I'm just saying it could be made better. The other way would be to use a separate element rather than overwriting the current one, and hiding it so it doesn't disrupt the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can do what I want using these styles:

```
.more-text {
    line-height: 1.2em;
    display:none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.more-text-collapse {
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:400px;
    height:1.2em;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.more-text-expand {
    display:inline;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

I give each of `<divs>` just the `more-text` class which lets them spread to their full width but hides them so they don't muck up the interface, then I compute their width and override class:

```
$('.more-text').each(function(i,el) {
    var width = $(this).width();
    $(this).addClass('more-text-collapse');
    if(width > 400) {
        $('<a>', {href:'#',class:'more-link'}).text('[more]').insertAfter(this);
    }
});
```

---

Actually, we can take the width out of the CSS entirely so that we only have to define it in one place:

```
var maxWidth = 400;
$('.more-text').each(function(i,el) {
    var width = $(this).width();
    if(width > maxWidth) {
        $(this).addClass('more-text-collapse').css('max-width',maxWidth);
        $('<a>', {href:'#',class:'more-link'}).text('[more]').insertAfter(this);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('more-text-expand');
    }
});
```

Would be nice if I could animate the text expanding...