# JS: Check if text is exceeding container width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Is there a js or jQuery function that will detect if the innerHTML or text is within a certain # of pixels from being clipped by its container?

I will need to do this for a few hundred elements on a page, so performance is a bit important.

Example - determine if the text in this `<td>` is within 5px of exceeding its width:

```
<td class="cell">
  12,3423
</td>

.cell {
   width: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
  var html_org = $(this).html();
  var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
  $(this).html(html_calc);
  var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
  $(this).html(html_org);
  return width;
};

$(function(){
   alert($('.cell').textWidth());    
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Hpyay/

It can be possible duplicate (**and above code copied from**) of [Calculating text width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap in something (p, div whatever) then you get that element width/height

```
 <td><p>text...</p></td>
```

make your calculation from `$("td>p").width()`

but if it's text only or image (with a `max-width:100%`) unless you no-wrap...