# Make the previous line of the text shorter than the next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to make the previous line of the text always shorter than the next if the text’s length is unknown? 
Somethig like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
et libero posuere pellentesque. Vivamus quis nulla justo.
vel lacinia sapien scelerisque eget. Vivamus ut velit elit. Donec
```

There is only a paragraph in HTML.

I have tried to do this with text-indent or :first-line or playing around with padding and width of a paragraph but none of them is working (as expected I think...).
Also have tried to somehow calculate the width of line using [Calculating text width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery) 
but also with no result (I'm not very good in jquery...).

I can’t add extra markup on the html (well, not directly, I can add it with scripts if necessary).
Preferably with css but I can add jquery too.

Please help.

Comment: You could add a `<br>` tag with jQuery after a certain number of characters (count the characters, then after X number, insert the tag). Then simply add 10 (for example) characters to the counter for each iteration?

Comment: @robooneus That’s a good idea, thanks. I will try to write this code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just use the selector p and attribute it to the section of there sentence where you want this paragraph to end for and use line-height to adjust its leading for instance http://jsfiddle.net/AMmYR/4/

```
    p {
        font:14px nor Futura, sans-serif;
        line-height:20px;
        color:#333;
    }

    <p>This is my first sentence.
<br>This is a very, very, very, long sentence
<br>This sentence is longer than the last, I don't know why.</p>
```

Comment: Then you will need to use the <br> selector within different parts of where you want to separate the paragraph. fiddle/code updated.