# Resize text box according to the selected date from the calenderextender

Tags: asp.net

I have used a calenderextender and i am displaying the date in long format and the selected date will be displayed in a textbox. so i want to resize my textbox according to the selected date. So how can i resize my textbox?

code:

Comment: please show us the relevant code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You just need to calculate the text width in JavaScript and set it to the textbox when date is changed. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery

Comment: i want to get the length of the selected date of calender extender and according to that length i want to change width of textbox. all using javascript..