# jQuery remove width doesn't work

Tags: jquery, width

I have the following jQuery to check how wide a  should be if I want to fit my text (just for testing purposes), but it always gives me the same width back as my own width, what am I doing wrong?

```
var newWidth = $(this).clone().insertAfter($(this));
newWidth.width("");
console.log(newWidth.width() + ' ' + $(this).width());
newWidth.remove();
```

For example, in my HTML I have an  tag that links to a German site, normally my  is 100 px width. but now, the title of this German site is "Rechtsschutzversicherungsgesellschaften" which is way too long text to fit in 100px. I want to see how wide my  should be, with my current font-size etc, in order to fit the whole text on one line.

Comment: What are you expecting this to do: `newWidth.width("");` ??? I guess you mean: `newWidth.css('width','');` to reset any CSS width rule apply to element in line

Comment: What exactly is this code supposed to do? It's very confusing.

Comment: try like this newWidth.width(0);

Comment: would it not be `newWidth.attr("Width","0px")` or `newWidth.css("Width","0px")` or similar ?

Comment: @SaintGerbil, no..https://api.jquery.com/width/ width would not be an attribute

Comment: Also if your using jquery to calculate width, 99% of the time your CSS is wrong.

Comment: Or try this newWidth.removeAttr('width');

Comment: @Liam I'd go "with should hopefully not be but cant be too sure".

Comment: @AshwiniVerma could be it if element is an image

Comment: Now please improve your question, no one seems to know what exactly you are looking for

Comment: sorry, was indeed unclear with my text. this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery) did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 newWidth.css('width', 'auto')
```

or

```
 newWidth.css('width', '');
```