# Calculate the width of the string base on font size and font style

Tags: jquery, html, css, fonts

I'm trying to determine the width of the string based on the font size and font style. 
 
But I'm not sure how to do it. I found a function on google, and I dont quite understand how it works.

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(text, font) {
    if (!$.fn.textWidth.fakeEl) $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl = $('<span>').hide().appendTo(document.body);
    $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.text(text || this.val() || this.text()).css('font', font || this.css('font'));
    return $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.width();
};
```

I tested this out, and get an output, I can get the width of the string, but What if I declare the font style and size? I'm not sure how to do it. Any idea on this one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [calculating text width with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery)

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking what if the user specify the font style and size?

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
  var html_org = $(this).html();
  var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
  $(this).html(html_calc);
  var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
  $(this).html(html_org);
 return width;
};
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery) subject.

Comment: I already seen that,. but what if,. the font style and font size is dynamically selected by the user?

Comment: You call the function each time that the size is changed ?!