# How to get the text input content width using javaScript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I have an `<input type="text" />` tag.

There may be too much content in it, and when the content length goes exceed the input width, it will be scrolling horizontally.

In fact, I want to control the width of tag, to make it varying according to the content.

So, is there any way to get the **content width** of the tag? Similar to the `scrollHeight` attribute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check this out

http://jsfiddle.net/philfreo/MqM76/

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(text, font) {
    if (!$.fn.textWidth.fakeEl) $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl = $('<span>').hide().appendTo(document.body);
    $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.text(text || this.val() || this.text()).css('font', font || this.css('font'));
    return $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.width();
};
```

[Calculating text width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery)

Comment: Thank you! Exactly good strategy to get accurate measurement! Great help for me!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you :)

Comment: I was just thinking of how to do this, you absolutely nailed it. good job

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("#chkText").on('input', function (){});` as below

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/8vdL8kbq/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#chkText").on('input', function () {
            var lng = $("#chkText").val().length;
            $("#chkText").width(lng * 10);
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="chkText"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust the length onkeypess or onkeyup:

A onkeypress example.
onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 5) + 'px';"

This should work if you put it inside the input tag. I think it would be good to define a minimum/maximum width.