# Way to figure out actual size of the text that went outside of the button in DOM

Tags: javascript

I would like to automatically go through several screen sizes and check if the button size is too small for the text inside if it so the text goes outside of the button. So far i get only a size of the button itself. Is there any way i can get actual size of the text on the page?

Comment: If you're familiar with jQuery, here's a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery

Comment: @Mr.White while that may work, jQuery isn't tagged, so let's assume OP is looking for a JS solution please.

Comment: That's why it's a comment ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript

Comment: compare the scroll-dimensions (scrollWidth, scrollHeight) to the offset-dimensions. If scroll exceeds offset, your content takes more space than the container.

Comment: @Thomas scroll vs offset works perfect for me. Thanks a lot. Can you make it as an answer and i will mark it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > compare the scroll-dimensions (scrollWidth, scrollHeight) to the offset-dimensions. If scroll exceeds offset, your content takes more space than the container.

```
function isOverflowing(node){
    return node.scrollWidth > node.offsetWidth || node.scrollHeight > node.offsetHeight
}
```