# How to detect text overflow in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to detect text overflow in `contenteditable` div, so that when text enter after the div width(800px), it will alert about the overflow. I am trying below code.

HTML

```js
var e = document.getElementById('test');
if (e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth) {
  alert("Overflow");
}
```

```css
#test{
  max-width: 800px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  font-size: 76px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" contenteditable="true">
  <div id="test">Click here..</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is working correctly , but there is a typo after `max-width: 800px` where `;` is missing. For which the width property is not getting applied.Add `;` & it will work

Comment: I added `;` but I want to detect `ellipsis` using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below one:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.content').on('input',function(){
    var e = document.getElementById('test');
     $.fn.textWidth = function() {
      var htmlCalc = $('<span>' + this.html() + '</span>');
       htmlCalc.css('font-size', this.css('font-size'))
      .hide()
      .prependTo('body');
      var width = htmlCalc.width();
      htmlCalc.remove();
      return width;
    };
    if ($('#test').textWidth() > $('#test').width()) {
      alert("Overflow");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#test{
  max-width: 800px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  font-size: 76px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content" contenteditable="true">
  <div id="test">Click here..</div>
</div>
```

`.textwidth()` function has taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width)